# Словить событие расшаривания

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет!

Ситуация такая.

Установил на сайт кнопки расшаривания share42.com

Клиент хочет, чтобы по факту расшаривания статей пользователю начислялась внутренняя валюта на счёт.

Но как словить событие, что пользователь в итоге расшарил статью?

Ведь он это делает в отдельно открывшемся окне выбранной соц. сети.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите просто отловить событие клика, то просто подписываетесь на это событие.
`$(document).on('click', '#share42 a', function(e){
    /**
     * Обрабатываем клик
     */
});`
А если вы хотите отработать и клик по кнопке в открывшимся окне, то не получится из-за междоменной безопасности.

Comment: В том то и дело, что первый клик не особо интересует, 

т.к. посетитель в итоге может не завершить действие в открывшемся окне соц. сети

Проблема как раз в этом )